# How to detect the event is trigger by end user? (ignore the event trigger by code)

Tags: excel, office-js

This question is from one of my customers who is developing an excel web add-in, they would like to detect whether the event is trigger by end-user or trigger by the code.

They have registered a Worksheet.onChanged event handler.

They would like to ignore the onChanged event change that triggers by their code themselves. and focus on Processing the event handler should only be done when the user changed the values.

Scenario: 
add-in listens to the sheetChange event. add-in user to enter values into the crosstabs, which the add-in will push to the server.
However, add-in API can also do some modification on the crosstabs, for example, the add-in can enable the user single click and drill down to get more data, their API logic will fetch data from the service and write to the crosstabs. however, the sheetChanged event will be triggered as well.

The solutions that the customer has been tried:

First try:
We tried to deregister the event handler before changing the values.
We then registered again after having the values changed.
This did not work as the deregistration is async and we were not able to await the deregistration.

Second try:
context.runtime.enableEvents = false
This is not possible as there are other events we are still interested in.

Current try:
We store the address of the changed range before changing the values.
In the onChanged handler, we compare the address.
If the same we do not do the logic.
After that, we delete the storage of the address again.

I also have tried to use a global flag and checking for that in the event handler, it doesn't work. here is my gist: https://gist.github.com/lumine2008/2b51d94d20cdca9ac9a0e97029dfd95c

Comment: You could consider setting a Global flag and checking for that in the event handler

Comment: I have tried this solution, it looks the global flag doesn't work, here is my sample gist. https://gist.github.com/lumine2008/2b51d94d20cdca9ac9a0e97029dfd95c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office.js doesn't provide such functionality yet.

Some workarounds, including a) context.runtime.enableEvents API, b) the global flag, or c) deregistering event before changing ranges and re-register event later, don't work cross-platform.
They will over-suppress events in some scenarios, which means some events triggered by user operations will be suppressed as well.

The most reliable way is your "current try"

1. Record the address of the to be changed range before changing the values.
2. In onChanged event handler, compare the event args with the address you recorded before. If it matches, clear the record and exit the event handler.

Comment: Thanks, how do i resolve the problem the event gets fired after the address storage has been removed again. Therefore the handler can not compare the address and is always executed.

Comment: why do you remove the address storage before the event gets fired?

Comment: That’s exactly the problem, the address storage should not be removed before the event gets filed.
 
It should be like
1. Store address
2. Set value to cell
3. Process sheet changed event (if comes from stored address ignore)
4. Remove address storage
 
But it is like that because event is fired with delay
1. Store address
2. Set value to cell
3. Remove address storage
4. Process sheet changed event (stored address comparison not possible)

Comment: I think the problem is the timing of "Remove address storage". Please try to remove address storage in event handler rather than after `await context.sync()`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a variable that chechs if the user is editing.

for example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    Static programChanging As Boolean

    programChanging = False

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If programChanging = False Then MsgBox("The User Is Changing")'*Do your code here*

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal As Range)

    programChanging = True

    Range("A1").Value = "The Program Is Changing"

    programChanging = False

End Sub
```

You can use the `programChanging` variable to check if the user is changing instead the if the program is changing but the principle stay the same.

**~~Edit~~**

You can also use one of the cells as the variable like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Range("A1").Value = "False" Then MsgBox("The User Is Changing")'*Do your code here*

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal As Range)

    Range("A1").Value = "True"

    Range("B5").Value = "The Program Is Changing"

    Range("A1").Value = "False"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the add-in is web add-in, not VBA, the web add-in is using javascript API (which is async mode), so the solution doesn't work for my customer.

Comment: 1. Isn't the activation for the add-in is via VBA?
2. You can use one of the cells in the sheet to check - just edited the answer.

Comment: No, this is not VBA add-in, this is JS web add-in, using office-js

Comment: As in js add-in, we have a context.sync(), so the sequence of API and Event is not in order. your answer is similar to global variable solution, which I validated, (i also share the gist in my original post), it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please help me with office js code? thank you.

Comment: If Using a cell in the worksheet does not work I think the best way is to do all of your programming either in VBA or JS